# PHP Regex Replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like `<div><center>[content]</center></div>`.
The "[content]" gets replaced by a php script that inserts a content from a database. 
I've solved that problem by using the str_replace function. Now I want to modify my script like that: If I type [content] it should replace it. If I write [[content]] it shouldn't do anything. I thought about using regex but whatever I try -> It does not work. 
If you don't understand me, just think back to c#, java,...: If I type \n, its a newline. If I type \n its "\n". I would be very thankfull if anyone could help.

Take a look at this example:

```
"aa[content]aa" -> aaMYCONTENTaa
"aa[[content]]aa" -> aa[[content]]aa
"aa[[[content]]]aa" -> aa[MYCONTENT]aa
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Template engine? Maybe use a existing one?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: **Don't roll your own solution to this problem.**  If ever there is a programming problem where it makes sense to rely on existing code that has been written, tested and debugged, this is it.  Templating engines exist all over for your free use.

Answer (score 1):

Pure regex solution is possible, but you are heading on a dangerous path of building your own templating engine. There are several solutions available ([smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) is the most popular one)

```
<?php
$str = preg_replace('([^\[]?)\[content\]([^\]]?)', '\1' . $yourcontent . '\2', $str);
?>
```

Explanation: `[^\\[]?` matches everything but the `[` character, including nothing. This means `[[content]]` doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

the code will replace `[content]` with the `$replace_content_with` value unless it has `[` before or `]` after

```
$original = '<div><center>[content]</center></div>';
$replace_content_with = 'my new content'; 
$pattern = '/([^\[])\[content\]([^\]])/i';
$new_data = preg_replace($pattern, '\1'.$replace_content_with.'\2', $original);
echo $new_data; //print <div><center>my new content</center></div>
```

note that if your replacement content include `\[SOME NUMBER]` in it - it might not work as expected

Comment: no. I it gets always replaced but not when there are two "[". -> see edited post

Answer (score 0):

Just replace '>[content]<' with '>whatever you want<'